# I get this error Could not invoke RNFSManager.readFile null on React Native Android. when uploading a Video

Tags: react-native

So, I have a React Native App that uploads a 2min 30s video, I get the error described above I am using RNFS.readFile to read the file `await RNFS.readFile(videoUrl, 'base64')`, the problem is in this line. this however works on 1min 20s video. Please help

Comment: What is the size of your file? It might because of large file size.

Comment: @Gogul-S Yes I agree, the file is large, but I guess the question here is what is the solution to that problem? and thanks for your response, appreciated...